# Are there any visualforce elements that allow you to order lists?

Tags: visualforce

I would like to have a VF component that allows the user to order a list and then to be able to save that list back to a record (I guess it would have to be saved in some serialized form).

I can't see any existing VisualForce components that deal with ordering. Is there anything out there?

Something like the component shown below which is used to order the columns of a view would be ideal.

[image: Selecting fields for a view]

Ideally I would be able to just include this component in a standard Salesforce detail page, but seeing as I would need to serialize and bind this list order on save, I guess I would need to visualforce the whole page. Seems like a lot of work just to include functionality for 1 extra component. Am I missing anything here?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Metadaddy has a Github repo with a multi-select component that mimics the standard page layout one. Maybe you could use parts of that?

[Multiselect Component](https://github.com/metadaddy-sfdc/Visualforce-Multiselect-Picklist/blob/master/src/components/MultiselectPicklist.component)

Answer (score 1):

There is indeed no standard component that supports this. You'd have to write your own VisualForce component.

It would indeed be beneficial to add it to the standard page layout, though..
What if you just ignore the 'standard' save operation on the object, but do a background save in your VF controller upon each change to the list order? You could include an 'saving...' actionStatus so the user is aware that the save to the list order is immediate.

Comment: Thanks @guy. Yes, I hadn't thought about triggering off a save onchange. Thanks for the idea.